# how to nest bootstrap collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create a nested bootstrap collapse. The collapse with id="ss11" which acts as the parent works when its button is clicked but the other nested do not work. where could I have gone wrong? how do I get those nested collapse to work when their buttons are clicked. here is the HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss11">
                                            ss1 : science
                                 </button>       
                            </div>

                            <div class="collapse" id="ss11">

                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12013/20141" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12013/20141">
                                                                2013/20141
                                         </button>

                                        </div>

                                         <div class = "collapse" id = "ss12013/20141">
                                                <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
                                        </div>


                                        <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12014/20151" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12014/20151">
                                                                2014/20151
                                                </button>   
                                        </div>

                                         <div class = "collapse" id = "ss12014/20151">
                                                <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12">
                                            ss1 : art
                                 </button>

                            </div>

                            <div class="collapse" id="ss12">
                                    <div class="card card-body">

                                        <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12013/20142" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12013/20142">
                                                                2013/20142
                                                </button>   
                                        </div>

                                         <div class = "collapse" id = "ss12013/20142">
                                                <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12014/20152" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12014/20152">
                                                                2014/20152
                                                </button>   
                                        </div>

                                         <div class = "collapse" id = "ss12014/20152">
                                                <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "**/**" in the name/ID; you can replace this with

- hyphen "**-**"
- Underscore "**_**"

to get the behavior that you're looking for...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="card-body">
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss11">
                                            ss1 : science
                                 </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="ss11">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12013_20141" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12013_20141">
                                                                2013/20141
                                         </button>

      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="ss12013_20141">
        <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12014-20151" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12014-20151">
                                                                2014/20151
                                                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="ss12014-20151">
        <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12">
                                            ss1 : art
                                 </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="ss12">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12013-20142" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12013-20142">
                                                                2013/20142
                                                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="ss12013-20142">
        <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ss12014_20152" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ss12014_20152">
                                                                2014/20152
                                                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="ss12014_20152">
        <p>hello lindsay lowhay</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```